# Проблемы с ProGuard при превращении строки в ресурс

Tags: proguard, android, java

Что бы превратить строку с ресурс, использую следующий метод

```
public static int getResId(String variableName, Class<?> c) {
    try {
        Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(variableName);
        return idField.getInt(idField);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
}
```

При использовании ProGuard этот метод не работает! Что нужно добавить в proguard.cfg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в proguard.cfg метку не обфусцировать класс(ы) которые передаются в качестве параметра в ваш метод `int getResId(String variableName, Class<?> c)`